# How i can disable the rich text effect of richtextbox?

Tags: c#, winforms

How I can disable the rich text effect of `richtextbox`? I am using Windows Forms, C#, .Net Framework 4.8 and I am trying to make a Notepad app. And richtext effect is so bad.

Example:

[image: Look]

That syntax highlighting and images.

I test these (codes from ChatGpt)

```
richTextBox1.Rtf = "";
```

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Rtf))
{
    richTextBox1.Rtf = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf);
}
else if (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Text))
{
    richTextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
}
```

1st code, it still can show images but not syntax highlighting. and I do not want use this. 2nd code, I did same with 1st I dont remember that outputs of code.

Comment: I don't think the textbox adds the syntax highlighting, but that it was already present in the copied text. If you don't want rich text, why use it?

Comment: idk, only richtextbox is scaleable from winforms components,

Comment: i want make it plaintext

Comment: And what if you forget about those `if`s and just use `richTextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);`?

Comment: thanks how i can update that post to answered

Comment: I added an answer. When you get a code fragment from anywhere (especially ChatGPT that doesn't really understand what it is saying), try and understand it before you use it

Answer (score 1):

"[RTF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)" stands for "Rich Text Format" - text PLUS formatting (like colors and fonts) and images.

If all you are interested in is the plain text version, then don't bother getting the RFT version, just use the plain text version of the clipboard's data.

So replace those `if`s with just

```
richTextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text);
```

That way you only get the plain-text version from the clipboard and use that to fill your richTextBox control.